# How to add an USB printer to the print management tool in Windows server?

Tags: printer, network-shares, network-printer, windows-server-2012-r2, sharing

I have some USB printers that i want to add to the print mnagement tool of windows server via the hostname that share the printer but the print management could not find them althought i could add network printers successfully .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) If the printers are USB - only, you need to connect the printer to the Server and then share it from there. That will normally work. However I do not like or recommend doing this.

(B) It will be much better to get a USB to Ethernet print server, put the printer on the print server and then network it normally. That will usually work and is a better way to connect the printer.

(B) is a much better way than (A).

Comment: Most USB-only printers are host-based (GDI, as distinct from PCL5/6 or PostScript) printers. With these printers, only use printservers that have your printer model listed in their compatibility list. If your printer is not listed, assume it won't work.